# Tracking drag-and-drop images with ID's of some sort

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

Ok, so I've come across a problem while making something for an eCommerce site.

Basically, it is a screen where the user can drag small buttons onto a bracelet which they had chosen on the previous screen. They drag their buttons onto the bracelet and once they like the combination they should be able to buy all 4 items (1 bracelet, 3 buttons) at once.

Here is a jsFiddle of how it basically works: http://jsfiddle.net/6xRXj/3/

The problem comes in, when I need to know which buttons are on the bracelet and which aren't. Is there a way to do this with drag-and-drop at all?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the code from jsFiddle...

HTML:

```
<div id="bracelet">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="div2" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Button-Red.svg" ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div3" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag2" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Button-Blue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div4" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag3" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div5" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag4" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Button-Purple.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div6" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag5" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Button-Orange.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div7" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag6" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Button-Green.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div8" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag7" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Button-Red.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div9" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag8" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Button-Blue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div10" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag9" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div11" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag10" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Button-Purple.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div12" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag11" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Button-Orange.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div13" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag12" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Button-Green.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 50px
}
.drop {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#bracelet {
    width:420px;
    height:75px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

JS:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    var el = ev.target;
    var parent = el.getAttribute("data-parent");

    if(!parent){
        el.setAttribute("data-parent", el.parentNode.id);
    }

    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", el.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

function dragEnd(ev){
    if(ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect == "none"){
         var parent = document.getElementById(ev.target.getAttribute("data-parent"));

        parent.appendChild(ev.target);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well we need to modify some part of your `drop` function. I have declared an `array` named **selectedItems**. When button is dragged from available items onto `bracelet` div, we put it in the array. If it is not dropped onto `bracelet`, we remove it from our array. You can click on `get` button to get selected items at any time.

```
////array to hold selected buttons
var selectedItems = [];

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text"),
        item = document.getElementById(data),
        i = 0,
        elem = document.getElementById(data);

    ev.target.appendChild(item);

    ////MODIFICATION
    if (ev.target.parentNode === document.getElementById('bracelet')) {
        selectedItems.push(elem);
    } else {
        i = selectedItems.indexOf(elem);
        selectedItems.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

To read selected items:

```
function getGems() {
    var pra = document.getElementById("ptag"),
        i = 0;
    pra.innerText ='';
    try {
        for (i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
            if (selectedItems[i]) {
                pra.innerText += ", " + selectedItems[i].id
            }
        }
    } catch (er) {
        pra.innerText = 'Error: ' + er;
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/6xRXj/5/

Answer (score 0):

Simple collect ID of your images into array e.g.:

```
var arr = [];

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

    // add ID of the image to array
    arr.push(data)

    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

This way you will know which images already added (and how many) and act accordingly. E.g. if 3 buttons already added - disallow adding more until at least one is removed.